# Custom chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

Does anybody know how to do a chart like the one in the image i m uploading? the main idea is to separate scores into 4 categories (25%, 50% %75, above): poor, below average, good, very good. But to have 4 different colors in the chart and a bar for each dataitem in black. For example, Customer A has a score of 90% so the bar should reach the green level[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of stacked area chart on the primary axis and column chart on the secondary axis axis.

A comprehensive step-by-step guide is on Jon Peltier's site [here.](http://peltiertech.com/excel-charts-with-horizontal-bands/)

Comment: i tried that wat, i m not quite getting it right. I cannot have them one on top of the other. i want the different colors as background and the items in front. How would you layout the data to make it happen, or what changes should i have to make in the chart, apart from using dif chart types

Comment: @FedericoSanchez You put the stacked area (or stacked column) on the primary axis and the individual scores on the secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to write it up right here.

Here's the data. I've included a column "Grade" before the students, because that's how I'm going to label the colored bands.

[image: data for column chart with colored band background]

And here's the sequence for making the chart.

Select the data range and insert a stacked column chart (top left).

Format any one of the columns, and set the Gap Width to 0, so the bands are continuous. Choose lighter shades of color to save people's retinas (top right).

Select and format the highest column series (the actual scores), and plot it on the secondary axis (middle left).

Select and format the same series (the scores), and set the gap width to 100, so the bands can be seen between the bars (middle right).

Delete the secondary vertical axis (right edge of chart), and hide the labels of the primary vertical axis (left edge of chart) by choosing the No Labels option for Label Position. Select the first point of each band (click once to select the band, then a second time to select the single point), and add a data label (bottom left).

Select each individual label (two single clicks needed), and choose to show the series name and not the value (bottom right).

[image]